# A compact set of measure zero can be covered by a finite number of open intervals with a total length less than the epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I'm studying Fourier analysis, and measure theory is too advanced a topic for me, so please give me a rather intuitive explanation.
I cannot understand how this idea applies to a subset of rational numbers.
I was given this description of that fact: [image]

[image]

As I understand it, for compact sets we can find N open covers that will cover all the elements of the set, and shrinking them as we want, but keeping the number of covers, we will still cover all the elements, is this implied here?

If it so, how can we shrink open covers and keeping the number of them to cover the set
$\{0\} \cup \left\{2^{-n} :n\in ℕ\right\}$

Comment: Note an "open cover" is a collection of open sets. $N$ is the number of open sets in a single open cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure is in some ways a generalization of the natural and intuitive mathematical notions of "length", "volume" et cetera. Thankfully, we don't actually require that robust of a theory of measure to reap the benefits of what it is to be "measure zero".

To start, it may to be useful to glean some intuition as to what we are representing here. Take for instance the set $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Though it is dense on this interval, there is an intuition that this set is in some ways "small", i.e. it is a countable subset of an uncountable interval. To match this intuition, we seek to develop some theory. This theory starts with some naive notions of volume that are easily computable, e.g. the length of an interval, or in general the volume of a $n$-dimensional rectangle. The idea here is that if we can cover some set with such closed rectangles, and make their volume arbitrarily small, it demonstrates that the covered set is in some way small.

In particular, keeping with the prior example, if we regard $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ as the countable union of its composite rational points, say $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} q_i$, we can for each rational point and arbitrary positive $\epsilon$ consider the enveloping interval $[q_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}, q_i +  \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}]$ with length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}$ (we can do this as the set is countable). It follows that we have:

$$\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} q_i \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} [q_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}, q_i +  \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}]$$
Where we additionally have the sum of lengths: $$ \sum_{i =1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon
$$
And thus $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is suitably small, and we regard this with the title "measure zero".

With regard to how compactness comes into play here (in general, as of course the provided example is not compact), it is relatively straightforward. If a set is already measure zero, we know that we have some cover of intervals/retangles with total length less than say $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. We can then cover those rectangles with open rectangles of arbitrarily little additional volume (say that the total $< \epsilon$), which of course still cover the original set. As the set is compact (and the covering by these new rectangles is an open cover) then, we are guaranteed a finite subcover of open rectangles that is still subject to this total volume constraint. Inclusion of the boundaries of each of these rectangles then yields a finite covering by closed rectangles of the same total volume. This criteria is referred to in literature some times as "Jordan content zero".

This, in totality, gives you a nonconstructive way to answer your question (that is, it just implies such a finite cover exists fulfilling arbitrarily small total length, as it is quite simple to show your provided set is at least measure zero with a nearly identical argument to the provided one). However, you now have the tools to address to your final question in a more satisfying way. In particular, I may note as a hint of sorts that $2^{-n}$ goes to zero rather quickly. Could you perhaps find a system to cover the points very close to $0$ and then constrain the outliers in suitably small intervals? In particular, you may note that even an arbitrarily small interval about $0$ only fails to cover a **finite** amount of points in this set.

Comment: So given set $\{0\} \cup \left\{2^{-n} :n\in ℕ\right\}$ there is no way to cover it with one number of open covers for each epsilon, and the less epsilon is, the bigger number of covers we might need, right?

Comment: I'm unsure if I'm entirely understanding what you wrote, but yes the idea is we need more, smaller intervals in the cover as we take the total length to be arbitrarily smaller. As I insinuated in the post, it may help to let $\epsilon > 0$, find some cover of points "close" to $0$ with total volume less than some fraction of $\epsilon$, and cover the finite remaining points with intervals that have lengths summing to less than the remaining fraction of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I think I get it. The difference between a compact and a just bounded set in this case is that if the set is open, for example Q∩[0,1], then we must have an infinite number of intervals in order for the total length of all intervals to be less then 1 (the boundary length) to cover all points of the set, and if the set is also compact, we can find a finite number of intervals if we require that the total length of intervals is less than the length of the set boundaries.

Comment: You’re partially correct. We definitely need infinite intervals to cover $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, and you are good to observe that this infinitude is *intuitively* how we get the total length below just the length of the interval. However, this set is not open (giving the density of the irrationals), it just also isn’t closed. What is special about compactness is is just the finite subcover of intervals.

Comment: that was helpful, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I have edited the post to describe things using closed intervals as opposed to the earlier open intervals, as this is "best practice" and is more consistent with some definitions in measure theory. It should also make the solution to your final problem a little more streamlined.

Comment: Noted, will read it again